# Calculation for finding max/min quadratic polynomial in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math

Let f(x)=ln(x) sin(x^2). Let x0<x1<x2 and f(x0)=f0, f(x1)=f1, and f(x2)=f2.

Let we construct a quadratic polynomial P2(x) which through the points (x0,f0), (x1,f1), (x2,f2).

Let x3 denote the maximum/minimum of P2(x). Now, I want to find x3 with this derived formula.

`x3=((x1^2-x2^2)*f0+(x2^2-x0^2)*f1+(x0^2-x1^2)*f2)/(2*((x1-x2)*f0+(x2-x0)*f1+(x0-x1)*f2))`

Now given three points:

```
x0=1.458634912623148600000000000000
x1=1.458634913920214200000000000000
x2=1.800000000000000000000000000000
```

I try to find x3 with this MATLAB program.

```
clear all;
clc;
syms x;
f=log(x)*sin(x^2);
x0=1.458634912623148600000000000000;
x1=1.458634913920214200000000000000;
x2=1.800000000000000000000000000000;
x3=1.458634856557844900000000000000;
f0=double(subs(f,x,x0));
f1=double(subs(f,x,x1));
f2=double(subs(f,x,x2));
x3=((x1^2-x2^2)*f0+(x2^2-x0^2)*f1+(x0^2-x1^2)*f2)/(2*((x1-x2)*f0+(x2-x0)*f1+(x0-x1)*f2));
f3=double(subs(f,x,x3));
fprintf('x0=%.30f\n',x0);
fprintf('x1=%.30f\n',x1);
fprintf('x2=%.30f\n',x2);
fprintf('f0=%.30f\n',f0);
fprintf('f1=%.30f\n',f1);
fprintf('f2=%.30f\n',f2);
fprintf('x3=%.30f\n',x3);
fprintf('f3=%.30f\n',f3);
```

The result is:

```
x0=1.458634912623148600000000000000
x1=1.458634913920214200000000000000
x2=1.800000000000000000000000000000
f0=0.320475806947705830000000000000
f1=0.320475806947705830000000000000
f2=-0.057749213248760499000000000000
x3=1.458634856557844900000000000000
f3=0.320475806947695120000000000000
```

**My question:**

Why the MATLAB result: x3 is outside of interval [x0,x2]? I think if I have quadratic polynomial P2(x) over x0<x<x2 then the max/min value is x0<x3<x2. Does this problem caused by an precision error of MATLAB?

Comment: "I think if I have quadratic polynomial P2(x) over x0<x<x2 then the max/min value is x0<x3<x2." Why do you think that? Take for example the quadratic formula `y = x^2`, and take `-10 < x < -1`; the minimum is still in `x = 0` which is outside of the initial interval.

Comment: In the interval -10<x<-1, the minimum value of y=x^2 is not equal to 0. It is equal to 1.

Comment: That is not what your formula is calculating though. What you're doing is finding the parabola that passes through your three points, and then finding the position of its minimum.

Comment: "caused by an precision error of MATLAB": no !

Comment: I have asked more detail in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4236576/quadratic-approximation-method-to-find-the-maximum-of-fx